# Cheapest way to connect ignition coil to spark plug for use in non-motoring application

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics

I don't know the first thing about how engines work, but am trying to make a spark with a [spark plug](https://www.amazon.co.uk/NGK-4626-BPMR7A-Spark-Plug/dp/B000BYNN3G/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=spark%2Bplug&qid=1599924217&quartzVehicle=138-258&replacementKeywords=plug&sr=8-3&th=1) and [ignition coil](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TAKPART-12V-Sports-Ignition-Coil/dp/B07Z81LGW6/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=12v%20ignition%20coil&qid=1599923352&sr=8-5) controlled by a power MOSFET.

While trying to find a way to connect them both, I saw that cables with proper connectors cost about £15/20. Is there a cheaper way? I might resort to ignition cable stripped at the ends, and though this might not be that safe, as long as it doesn't blow up in my face, I don't care. I do care about interference, however, as there will be a computer close to it while it's on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered salvage yards for the appropriate components?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the environment and things like controlling radio interference even a bare copper wire can be used.

But, if it is working and you get too close, then you can get a shock.

I replaced the resistive cables on my V8 with copper core spark ignition cable - had to make them from scratch though, easy as I had all the connectors and boots to do that though.

Most [good] auto-electricians kept both types of cable in stock, copper core and resistive, as it was easier to make a new plug lead than wait for one to be ordered, but given how they are molded into the coil pack now then you might just be lucky that they still have it on the dusty shelf. And the cable was only a quid a foot (dollar a foot) so cheap...

Comment: Thanks, that's probably what I'll do. I'm assuming wire wrapped around the contacts and electrical tape will work too?

Answer (score 1):

Get you down the road right quick and sharpish to Fred Friendly's Car Repair Garage (it's right on the corner, you pass it every day on the way to the pub) and ask to root about in his trash bin for some discarded spark plug wires. Get a fistful if possible, take them home, and test them until you find one that works.

Note that most plug wires of modern manufacture use a carbonized string inside to conduct the high voltage. This adds resistance to the spark circuit which limits current and extends the duration of the spark, but requires care to make contact with. You will find a bent metal thingus pressed onto the end of the wire that plugs into the distributor or ignition module, do not remove this- it has a sharp spike that goes up into the inside of the wire and contacts the string inside. This then presses into the outlet of the spark coil.

Spark coils, plugs, and ignition modules are NOTORIOUS for generating all sorts of radiated and conducted electromagnetic trash. You will need to shield and then ground all the high-tension wiring, contact me at [www.nielsenkillowatt.com](http://www.nielsenkillowatt.com) for further instructions.

Comment: I'll definitely have a look around for scrap wires, thanks.
Would eyelet wire terminals and insulated copper wire work also?
I was thinking grounded aluminium foil wrapped around the wires would do the trick to shield it to an extent? It's only a boj job :P

Comment: yes the eyelets would work but self-adhesive copper foil is preferred for the shielding. This is sold in sheets or rolls in music shops for shielding the insides of electric guitars, and also at stained glass shops for edging pieces of glass that are to be soldered together.

Comment: Ah ok I'll get some of that, thanks.
As for the connections, do you have to ground the spark plug? And also how would you get a wire inside the tube-like protrusion on the ignition coil?

As an aside, your guitars are very impressive!

Comment: thanks! the spark system indeed requires a ground path. a plug wire is a press-fit into the spark coil protrusion- remember to include the thingus.